# Controls all getting identical names in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to add a series of controls to a repeater inside of an UpdatePanel. The problem is that the repeater is not giving the controls unique ids. The result I want is a set of multiple panels like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
  <contentpanel>
    <div id="groupdiv>
      <div id="HeaderDiv>
        <asp:checkbox id="headerItem" />
      </div>
      <div id="townDiv">
        <asp:checkbox id="townItem" />
        <asp:checkbox id="townItem" />
        <asp:checkbox id="townItem" />
      </div>
    </div>
  <contentpanel>
</asp:updatePanel>
```

it is important to note though that all of the above is built in code behind, similar to the following. To describe what is going on in the code below: all checkboxes are build and added to a div to hold them. When a new group starts, or on the last repeater item, these divs are added to the updatepanel which is added to a placeholder inside the repeater.

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        if ("first Item In Group")
        {
            if ("New Group")
            {
                groupDiv.Controls.Add(HeaderDiv);
                groupDiv.Controls.Add(townDiv);
                repeaterUpdate.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(groupDiv);
                ((PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("contentPanel"))
                    .Controls.Add(repeaterUpdate);
            }

            repeaterUpdate = new UpdatePanel();
            repeaterUpdate.ID = "UpdatePanel";

            groupDiv= new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            HeaderDiv= new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            townDiv= new HtmlGenericControl("div");

            //code to build header checkbox
            //note this is hard coded and not in the repeater

            HeaderDiv.Controls.Add(headerItem);

            //code to build first repeater item for each group

            townDiv.Controls.Add(townItem);
        }
        else
        // this will be when a header group is not needed
        {
            //code to build additional repeater townItem checkboxes

            townDiv.Controls.Add(townItem);

            if (last item in repeater)
            {
                groupDiv.Controls.Add(HeaderDiv);
                groupDiv.Controls.Add(townDiv);
                repeaterUpdate.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(groupDiv);
                ((PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("contentPanel"))
                    .Controls.Add(repeaterUpdate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried adding the elements immediately instead of waiting until the full group is built but I end up with the same error. Why is the repeater not giving my checkboxes unique IDs. Also it is important to note that I need to let the repeater give the checkboxes a unique id because I will need to iterate over them later and cannot give them an id like

```
checkbox.ID = "townItem" + repeater.PrimaryKey
```

Comment: a simple google search could have saved you the time 
[Using a Repeater inside of UpdatePanel](http://forums.asp.net/t/1971740.aspx?Using+a+Repeater+inside+of+UpdatePanel+with+UpdateProgress)

Comment: @DJKRAZE That is the reverse of what I want to do. I have tried that method but because of all the logic in my OnItemDataBound function that method does not work. It will update the repeater recalling the function and effectively breaking the page. The UpdatePanel needs to be inside the repeater.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Also adding clientIDMode="AutoID" does not fix the problem. The repeater's normal behavior is similar to this so it still creates items with the same IDs.